# Navigation drawer 2.3 gingerbread

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I am trying to implement navigation drawer in my android app. I used This tutorial : http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/
which shows to implement the navigation drawer with the use of fragments. But my app force closes as I am trying to run it on API 10 (Gingerbread)

But it works only on 3.0 Honeycomb+. How do I make it work on 2.3 Gingerbread+ and in fullscreen mode. Please I need help!

Thanks in advance!

StackTrace

```
01-09 16:01:07.971  16470-16470/com.Chinmay.navigationdrawer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL     EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.Chinmay.navigationdrawer.MainActivity.getActionBar
    at com.Chinmay.navigationdrawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please add your stacktrace for the crash.

Comment: google it a bit before asking.., take a look at this http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Try using action bar Sherlock which supports this functionality in lower versions too. you can find demo [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/actionbarsherlock-samples)

Comment: I googled it but couldn't get a great answer which is why I asked it here. I am a beginner so forgive me if I've made any mistakes.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer Please help me out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Navigation Drawer is not available for Android 2.3 Gingerbread. You must use AppCompat support library to use Navigation Drawer on older versions. There is a good tutorial [here](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

Pre honeycomb there is no `ActionBar` available. That's why your App crashes at the call `getActionBar()`.

You have to use the SherlockActionbar library or the ActionbarCompat from the support library. If you use one of these change the call to `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: Is there any way to implement the navigation drawer without using the action bar? Basically I don't want the actionbar as my app is using fullscreen mode horizontally! Please suggest and help.

Comment: @ChinmayDabke The AppIcon of the ActionBar is used to open/close the NavigationDrawer. It isn't necessary for further functionality. Without the ActionBar you have the possibility to open the Drawer with the swipe gesture or you can add any Button to open/close the Drawer. The AppIcon is just the standard way for interaction.

Comment: So I cn use the navigation drawer in full screen mode in horizontal orientation as well? Thanks Steve!

Answer (score 2):

You're calling [`getActionBar()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getActionBar%28%29) which has been added in API level 11.
You'll need to extend `SherlockActivity` or use the compatibility library and then call `getSupportActionBar()` in order to fix the issue.

Comment: Is there any way to implement the navigation drawer without using the action bar? Basically I don't want the actionbar as my app is using fullscreen mode horizontally! Please suggest and help.