# Android NavigationDrawer API <11

Tags: android, api, android-actionbar, drawer

I have the NavigationDrawer with minSDK11 and Theme.Holo, and with Fragments using the ActionBar. Now I would like to extend my application even for devices with API <11, without having to make the application again. What better way? Thanks

Comment: You can add support library, to use navigation drawer in android sdp<11.

Comment: I think your question is duplicate. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017516/navigation-drawer-2-3-gingerbread

Answer (score 0):

Use [action bar sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

The library will automatically use the native action bar when appropriate or will automatically wrap a custom implementation around your layouts. This allows you to easily develop an application with an action bar for every version of Android from 2.x and up.

this is the best you can do